# CSS animated underline in position absolute issue

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with an animated underline effect I got from [HERE](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/).
When I apply i to the code for elements inside and absolute div, the underline applies to the entire div, not the a tag itself.

Here's the html of the portion:

```
<div class="navbar">
            <div class="elem">
                <p><a href="#" class="tt">Element</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="m">Element</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="m">Element</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="m">Element</a></p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Minimal codepen: [HERE](https://codepen.io/aln447/pen/VeqqMv?editors=1100)

Any help would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to position the anchor link since it is the 'parent' to the pseudo-element.

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qbLLoE?editors=1100)

```
.navbar a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    position: relative; /* here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `position:relative` to the paragraph element

```
.navbar p {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVbbQe?editors=1100